How to derive standard errors of regressors in quasi-Poisson regression?
Suppose I want to relax a Poisson Regression to allow for overdispersion and apply a quasi-likelihood approach:
$$E[y_i|x_i] = exp(x_i^T \beta)$$
$$Var[y_i|x_i] = \phi \cdot \mu_i$$
In other words, leave the score function unchanged and thus keep a conditional mean model, but not a conditional probability model anymore.
Estimate $ \hat{\phi} $ with the residuals:
$$ \hat{\phi} = \frac{1}{n - k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (r_i^2) $$
where the Pearson residuals ( r_i ) are given by:
$$ r_i = \frac{(y_i - \hat{\mu}_i)}{\sqrt{\hat{\mu}_i}} $$
But how do I get now from $Var[y_i|x_i]$ to the standard errors from a classical output like in R, when using glm(... family=quasipoisson) function?

if you want standard errors on the coefficient estimates you want something like sqrt(phi*diag(vcov(fitted_model)))

Thanks! So overdispersion is more or less directly reflected in the standard errors of the parameters? Say we have a normal Poisson regression with significantly smaller standard errors than Quasi-Poisson: Is it valid to conclude that there might be an overdispersion?
